# how to avoid Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) ? in perl v5.8.4

Tags: perl, initialization

```
$ perl -e 'use warnings;my ($a,$b);$c=$a.$b;print $c'
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at -e line 1.
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at -e line 1.
```

I see that

I decided it

```
use 5.8.4;
use strict;
use warnings;
use Test::More tests => 2;
my ( $start, $end, $sysid, $ver, $tradetype );
( $start, $end ) = ( 1, 10 );
my $test = make_string( $start, $end, $sysid, $ver, $tradetype );
is( $test, "1,10,,,\n", "make index string" );
is( make_string( 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ), "0,0,0,0,0\n", "test number" );

sub make_string {
    my @input      = @_;
    my @input_init = map { !defined $_ ? '' : $_ } @input;
    my $rezult     = join q{,}, @input_init;
    return $rezult . "\n";
}
```

i decided that question, but i I wanted to know how this problem can be solved in other people

Comment: You see what?  ("I see that" isn't complete in this context.)  You decided what?  You've not initialized `$sysid`, `$ver` and `$tradetype` before the call to `make_string()`.  You should really think about upgrading to, say, Perl 5.14.1 (you're three main releases behind current).  (FWIW: your test code works cleanly with 5.10.0 and 5.14.1 on my Mac.  I don't have Perl 5.8.x compiled on it.)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler the second example works. in `sub make_string` he initializes them with ternary operator with map. But I still don't understand his question. I suppose it's something about thi 1st example.

Comment: @tze, That's probably because he didn't ask a question.

Comment: *"I see that. I decided it."* So true. So true.

Comment: So...uh...you had a problem with your first example and your second example fixes it. Right, and what's the problem? The two examples don't really have anything to do with each other.

Answer (score 11):

The most common way to join a group of unconditionally defined objects is to remove the values by `grep`

```
join '', grep { defined; } @_;
```

However you want an indicator for each value, defined or not.

```
sub make_string { join( ',', map { $_ || '' } @_ ); }
```

But here is another thing you can do.

```
my $str
    = do { no warnings 'uninitialized'; 
           join( ',' @_ ); 
      };
```

Some people have needless reservations about turning warnings off.

Comment: isn't it better using `map { $_ // '' }`?

Comment: thanks for answer, i use  5.10.0 and 5.14.1,
but on my production environment v5.8.4
i think that 
 no warnings 'uninitialized'; 
is not best way
and 
my $str
    = do { no warnings 'uninitialized'; 
           join( ',' @_ ); 
      };
code not work

Answer (score 3):

Either test for definedness or disable warnings surrounding the code where you don't want to see the complaint:

```
use warnings;
...
no warnings;
my ($a, $b);
my $c = $a . $b;
use warnings;
```

Comment: Or better `no warnings qw(uninitialized);`, see [perllexwarn](http://perldoc.perl.org/perllexwarn.html)

Answer (score 0):

Since `undef` value does not represent a string and binary operator `.` concatenates two strings you can't avoid the warning with `use warnings`.

Either `$a` and `$b` must be strings.

However, as stated in other answers you *can* disable warnings just for uninitialized variables.

Comment: Please comment when downvoting, so that the downvote itself can be useful to learn something new.