# Turn off warnings in Perl MySQL insert statement?

Tags: mysql, perl, dbi

Am using Perl DBI to insert into MySQL database.  Some of the variables are deliberately set to

```
   undef
```

where the value for the variable is not available and the variable is therefore intended to be

```
   NULL
```

in the database.

However, I get warnings on uninitialised values at the insert statement.

What is best practice here?  As far as I can see there is no other way to get NULL properly assigned in the MySQL database except to set the variable to undef when there is no value available.  Should I turn off warnings for uninitialised values?

Comment: Can you show your warning message?

Comment: Use of uninitialized value $blah in concatenation (.) or string at null_to_database line 1450.

Comment: @user1849286 You are doing what apparently many people are doing when using the DBI module: Not using placeholders. That can be dangerous and problematic, and it certainly is not easier. Refer to the documentation.

Comment: This warning abot concatenation undef value. More details here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8156002/how-to-avoid-use-of-uninitialized-value-in-concatenation-in-perl-v5-8-4

Answer (score 3):

You are probably doing

```
$dbh->do("INSERT INTO Foo ( field ) VALUES ( '$x' )");
```

In which case you are inserting an empty string, not NULL, when `$x` is `undef`. It also breaks for other values (e.g. those that contain single quotes). This is what you should be doing:

```
my $x_lit = defined($x) ? $dbh->quote($x) : 'NULL';
$dbh->do("INSERT INTO Foo ( field ) VALUES ( $x_lit )");
```

Or better yet:

```
$dbh->do("INSERT INTO Foo ( field ) VALUES ( ? )", undef, $x);
```

Comment: So does that mean I can go through the script assigning the value 'NULL' wherever a value does not exist and still expect a proper definition of NULL in the MySQL database?

Comment: Assigning the value 'NULL' doesn't create a proper null value in the database - it creates a value of the text string 'NULL' correct?  Above, isn't the assignment 'NULL' what you are using to insert a NULL value if $x is not defined - and therefore does not work.

Comment: No, you can't. Putting the string `NULL` in `$x` won't work, which is why I didn't do that. Note that lack of quotes around `NULL` in the constructed SQL statement.

Comment: There are single quotes around NULL in the constructed SQL statement.  But ok, I see what is going on, we basically have to create an unquoted NULL in the literal values used within the SQL statement, thanks

Comment: No there aren't. My code does not put quotes around `NULL` when `$x` is undef.

Comment: And no, you don't have to do that. You could also use placeholders like I've shown.

Comment: my $x_lit = defined($x) ? $dbh->quote($x) : 'NULL';  doesn't that say if $x is undef then $x_lit = 'NULL'? (ie. with single quotes?)